# How to load the modules for Apache2?

Tags: apache2, configuration

I want to load some modules for proxy configuration. I have the modules installed under `/etc/apache2/mods-available/xxx`

How do I load them into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/xxx` ?

In other words, in which configuration should this be placed?

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can enable modules using [a2enmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/a2enmod.8.html). For example:

```
a2enmod proxy
```

That command will create a symlink inside `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` that points to the module in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`.

Likewise, to disable a module, use [a2dismod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/a2dismod.8.html). That command will remove the symlink from the `mods-enabled` directory.

**Bonus tip:** there exist similar commands to enable/disable sites: look at [a2ensite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/a2ensite.8.html) and [a2dissite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/a2dissite.8.html).

Comment: So we do not need the "LoadModule" line at all?