# how to fix Wordpress on a ubuntu 18.4 desktop using commandline

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make a Wordpress website for my local PC. I have done it on Windows before so I was thinking why not learn how to do it on Ubunutu.

After a cobble of days with YouTube videos and guides that doesn't help I was thinking I will try here

My first problem I actually run in is that when I install my MySQL I don't get the option to give it a password that I have to do manual.

After that I log in on my MySQL and make a database.

I install WordPress.

Now my second problem appears.
When I try to set it up by using *localhost/wordpress* in my browser I came into a WordPress set-up site but when I give it my informations it fails and that's here I go stuck

Can any help me?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact errors you get, and maybe output from relevant log-files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install and set up Apache 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007425/how-do-i-install-and-set-up-apache-2)

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** This answer does not help to fix your specific issue with the installation. It is rather another way to run wordpress very easily which might be helpful to you or others finding this question.

---

You could use `docker` to run [wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) in just a few seconds:

1. [Install docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)
2. Create a folder somewhere, e.g.

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/opt/wordpress
   ```
3. Create a file `docker-compose.yaml` in that folder with following content:

   ```
   version: '3.1'

   services:

     wordpress:
       image: wordpress
       restart: always
       ports:
         - 8080:80
       environment:
         WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example

     mysql:
       image: mysql:5.7
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
   ```
4. `cd` to the folder and run `docker-compose up`
5. Point your browser to `localhost:8080`. Done.

---

This is just the basic installation procedure.
For persistance you need to add a volume, [see here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) for more details.